# What happens if citizens take off the PM?

Tags: shimoseka

In the first episode we learn that the PM (Peace Makers) are used to check if a citizen is using blacklisted words.

Couldn't they just take take the device off when they aren't in public instead of having to use some cellphone to disrupt the PM's surveillance?

[image: Cellphone that disrupts PM's surveillance]

Comment: It's affixed to their throats, it would probably just go off, like when a lewd word is used, and alert the Decency Squad.